# Setting token and tokenSecret in PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService

Tags: java, paypal

i am trying to implement a Paypal API transaction Search call in java.
The following works:

```
PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(new File("sdk_config.properties"));
            SetAccessPermissionsReq perm = new SetAccessPermissionsReq();
            TransactionSearchRequestType transSearch = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
            transSearch.setStartDate(startDate);
            transSearch.setEndDate(endDate);

            TransactionSearchReq request = new TransactionSearchReq();
            request.setTransactionSearchRequest(transSearch);

            TransactionSearchResponseType response = service.transactionSearch(request);

            List ans = response.getPaymentTransactions();
```

However, I cannot find how to load a token and tokenSecret into the service object to return the transaction search for a third party Paypal account for which I have the proper tokens.

Something simple like

```
service.setToken(token);
```

does not work, as PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService does not have a setToken method.

It is possible to initialize the 'service' object with a java.util.Properties file, but I cannot find an example of this anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example configuration file is available in the SDK itself.  If you can't find it then here is a link to the [current version on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java/raw/d3e6e4f9835a4b0707efbcdce9bc5a3a5a5b1dad/merchantsample/src/main/resources/sdk_config.properties)

Comment: thanks.. I solved this by using a method from the BasicService class, even though Netbeans says it is deprecated. service.setAccessToken(token); (netbeans displays the method with a strikethrough), but it still works.